# Display error when the textfields are null

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to display an error message place in a `<span>` element when a certain textfield is null, the textfields are dynamically created and place inside a `<div>`, I can't display the message that the field is null, always getting error like cannot set property of innerhtml of undefined.

```
var quiztxtBox = document.getElementsByName('quiztxtBox[]');
var err = document.getElementsByName('errMessage');

for (var i=0; i<quiztxtBox.length; i++) {
    if (quiztxtBox[i].value == "") {
        quiztxtBox[i].focus();
        quiztxtBox[i].style.backgroundColor = '#f6d9d4'; 
        err[i].innerHtml = "Textbox is null"
    } else {
        quiztxtBox[i].style.backgroundColor = '#fff'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `err[i]` is undefined. Show you markup. Do your spans have name attributes?

Comment: May be you should use like this for err variable. var err = document.getElementsByName('errMessage[]');

Comment: the errMessage is the name of the span.

Comment: Just inspect contents of your `err` node list.